# How to disable output buffering in Python simplhttpserver

Tags: python, python-2.7

The below script snippet is part of a script that implements a simplehttpserver instance which triggers a third party module upon a GET request. I am able to capture the third party module's stdout messages and send them out to the webbrowser.

Currently, the script collects all the stdout messages and dumps them to the client, when the invoked module has been finished....

Since I want each message to appear in the browser as it is sent to stdout, output buffering needs to be disabled.

How do I do that in pythons simplehttpserver?

```
def do_GET(self):
    global key

    stdout_ = sys.stdout #Keep track of the previous value.
    stream = cStringIO.StringIO()
    sys.stdout = stream

    ''' Present frontpage with user authentication. '''
    if self.headers.getheader('Authorization') == None:
        self.do_AUTHHEAD()
        self.wfile.write('no auth header received')
        pass
    elif self.headers.getheader('Authorization') == 'Basic '+key:
        if None != re.search('/api/v1/check/*', self.path):
            recordID = self.path.split('/')[-1]
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS')
            self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization")
            self.end_headers()
            notStarted = True
            while True:
                if notStarted is True:
                    self.moduleXYZ.start()
                    notStarted is False
                if "finished" in stream.getvalue():
                    sys.stdout = stdout_ # restore the previous stdout.
                    self.wfile.write(stream.getvalue())
                    break
```

**Update**

I modified the approach to fetch the status messages from the class, instead of using stdout. I included Martijns nice idea of how to keep track of changes.

When I run the server now, I realize that I really need threading? It appears that the script waits until it is finished before it proceeds to the while loop.

Should I better implement threading in the server or in the module class?

```
   def do_GET(self):
        global key

        ''' Present frontpage with user authentication. '''
        if self.headers.getheader('Authorization') == None:
            self.do_AUTHHEAD()
            self.wfile.write('no auth header received')
            pass
        elif self.headers.getheader('Authorization') == 'Basic '+key:
            if None != re.search('/api/v1/check/*', self.path):
                recordID = self.path.split('/')[-1]
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS')
                self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization")
                self.end_headers()
                self.moduleABC.startCrawl()

                while True:
                    if self.moduleABC.done:
                        print "done"
                        break
                    output = self.moduleABC.statusMessages
                    self.wfile.write(output[sent:]) 
                    sent = len(output)


            else:
                self.send_response(403)
                self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                self.end_headers()
```

**Update 2 (working)**

This is my updated GET method. The class object of the third party module is instatiated in the GET method. The module's main method is run in a thread. I use Martijns ideas to monitor progress.

It took me a while to figure out that it is necesarry to append some extra bytes to the status text that is sent to the browser to force a buffer flush!

Thanks for your help with this.

```
def do_GET(self):
    global key
    abcd = abcdModule(u"abcd")

    ''' Present frontpage with user authentication. '''
    if self.headers.getheader('Authorization') == None:
        self.do_AUTHHEAD()
        self.wfile.write('no auth header received')
        pass
    elif self.headers.getheader('Authorization') == 'Basic '+key:
        if None != re.search('/api/v1/check/*', self.path):
            recordID = self.path.split('/')[-1]
            abcd.setMasterlist([urllib.unquote(recordID)])
            abcd.useCaching = False
            abcd.maxRecursion = 1
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS')
            self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization")
            self.end_headers()
            thread.start_new_thread(abcd.start, ())
            sent = 0

            while True:
                if abcd.done:
                    print "done"
                    break
                output = abcd.statusMessages

                if len(output) == sent + 1:
                    print abcd.statusMessages[-1]
                    self.wfile.write(json.dumps(abcd.statusMessages)) 
                    self.wfile.write("".join([" " for x in range(1,1000)]))
                    sent = len(output)           


        else:
            self.send_response(403)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            self.end_headers()
    else:
        self.do_AUTHHEAD()
        self.wfile.write(self.headers.getheader('Authorization'))
        self.wfile.write('not authenticated')
        pass


    return
```

Comment: Why not attach `sys.stdout` to `self.wfile` then?

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with buffering, as you are redirecting stdout to a `StringIO` object.

Comment: `notStarted is False` is a no-op; the boolean result is discarded. Is `moduleXYZ.start()` running a thread?

Comment: Is there no other way to detect that the `moduleXYZ` thread has completed other than seeing if it has output `finished`?

Comment: The module is not running in a thread so far. If I would move it into a thread, is it possible to retrieve status information from the third party module, if that status information was stored in a class variable of that module?

Comment: *That depends*. Probably, but there is not enough context here to say anything about that really.

Comment: I'll see how far I can get and post how far I get

Answer (score 0):

You really want to fix `moduleXYZ` to not use `stdout` as the only means of output. This makes the module unsuitable for use in a *multithreaded* server, for example; two separate threads calling `moduleXYZ` will lead to output being woven together in unpredictable ways.

However, there is *no stream buffering* going on here. You are instead capturing all `stdout` in a `cStringIO` object, and only when you see the string `"finished"` in the captured string do you output the result. What you should do there instead is continuously output that value, tracking how much of it you already sent out:

```
self.moduleXYZ.start()
sent = 0
while True:
    output = stream.getvalue()
    self.wfile.write(output[sent:])
    sent = len(output)
    if "finished" in output:
        sys.stdout = stdout_
        break
```

Better still, just connect `stdout` to `self.wfile` and have the module write *directly* to the response; you'll need a different method to detect if the module thread is done in this case:

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = self.wfile
self.moduleXYZ.start()
while True:
    if self.moduleXYZ.done():
        sys.stdout = old_stdout
        break
```

Comment: thanks. I am not running the module in a thread right now. haven't tried threading yet. do I need to implememnt that in the webserver or in the third party modules class? and if I implement threading, will it then be possible to poll each class object in a thread individually (if status messages are stored in a class variable)

Comment: @Jabb: if you are implementing that third-party module, consider having it accept `self.wfile` to write *directly*.

Comment: @Jabb: there is no need to use threading in that module here; just wait for it to complete.

Comment: thanks for your ideas of how to keep track of changes in the status messages etc! I think I still need threading though

Comment: @Jabb: If you are *not* using threading just use my second option; connect `sys.stdout` to `self.wfile`, remove the loop. `moduleXYZ.start()` will not return until it has completed its job *anyway*. Remove `while True:`, the `if`, unindent `sys.stdout = old_stdout` and remove the `break`.

Comment: your objection that the stdout method will lead to unexpected behaviour in a multithreaded environment is correct. in fact multiple calls will be made to the api concurrently. so threading appears to be the only alternative